# at react native android,custom entryFile does't work when it's debug mode

Tags: react-native

when i define the entryFile at build.gradle,run in debug mode,it still load index.android.js instead of index.android2.js.

```
project.ext.react = [
   entryFile: "index.android2.js",
   bundleInDebug: false,
   bundleInRelease: true,
   root: "../../"
]
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `git grep index.android` will show you what you need to change

Note: Do not forget to overide getJSMainModuleName method

```
@Override
protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
return "android/demo_app/index.android";
}
```

here android is project folder, demo_app is directory in which all js files are situated. You can give any path like this.